# How do I call something that can be doubled with one word? (double-able)

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose that we're playing a card game. One of the rules is that you can double the numerical value of a card if it fulfills a set of conditions.

So, there are two types of cards: those that can be doubled and those that can't.

Is there a single word that can be used to describe a card that "can be doubled"? Basically, **double-able**.

> None of your cards is double-able!

Which sounds a bit awkward. I know that I can say

> None of your cards can be doubled!

But I was wondering if there is a one-word solution.

Answer (score 3):

*Doubleable* and [*doublable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doublable) both seem fine. Which one is a question, I suppose, of whether you pronounce it with four syllables or three. I was looking for roots of Old English origin that might sound more natural, but the closest I found were:

- *twofold* ⇒ *twofoldable*
- *-lic* ⇒ *twicelike*
- *-bære* ⇒ *twobearing*

None of these beats *doublable* for a modern English coinage.

Comment: Doublable has a precise meaning, but when you play cards, you're prone to engage in libation, and God be with ya then with those liquids and obstruents...

Answer (score 1):

Also consider:
• *[twinnable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twinnable)*, “That can be twinned”
• *[dual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dual#Adjective)*, in the sense “Exhibiting duality; characterized by having two (usually equivalent) components”
• *[duplicative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicative#Adjective)*, “of, related to, or being a duplicate”
• *[redundant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redundant#Adjective)*, “Superfluous; exceeding what is necessary” and also  “Duplicating or able to duplicate the function of another component of a system...”

Comment: +1 for *twinnable*, but the rest seem misleading (without game specific definition).

Answer (score 1):

#### *[duplicable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duplicable)*

adj. capable of being duplicated.

Comment: This word has a less spot on meaning than _doubleable_ has, but for an informal setting such as the given, I'd rather be imprecise and understood than precise and laughed at.  ^__^

Comment: You could specify it a bit more and say ‘reduplicable’—that means exactly what the asker is looking for, though I've only ever heard it about sounds and words in language that can be reduplicated.